# When I have less than 100 rep, and my answer became community wiki post, can I have the privilege to edit the post?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

Today, I noticed the rule "a much lower reputation (100 instead of 2000) is needed to edit a community wiki post" in [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)
Does this mean the Community Wiki posts do not allow anyone, including the original author, with reputation of less than 100 to edit it? Does that include suggesting edits?

If the answer is yes, then it seems there is a problem in logic. If I have less than 100 rep, and my answer became community wiki post, I would not be able to edit my post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Authors can edit their original posts regardless of the reputation limits in place for other users.

As a test: try editing your post now. You don't have 2,000 reputation, but you're still allowed to edit. Same thing for Community Wiki.

This also applies to suggested edits: anyone can suggest an edit even if they don't have the reputation (100 or 2000) to edit it themselves. This even applies to unregistered users: reputation is not a factor when it comes to suggested edits.

Authorship supersedes the suggested editing functionality; if you're the author of a post, you don't need to suggest an edit and wait for approval: your edits will take effect immediately.

Comment: Users whose rep less than 100 can suggest edit community wiki post?

Comment: @Roy yes: anyone can suggest an edit, even if they're not a registered user.